# MySQL selecting featured items on top

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a table with field `item_featured` with value Yes or No. Now I want to sort all the rows with featured YES on top followed by non-featured item. All will be in DESC order of id. Is it possible to do using 1 query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a conditional sort:

```
order by (item_featured = 'Yes') desc, id desc
```

Rationale: expression `item_featured = 'Yes'` yields `1` if the condition is fullfilled, else `0` - so a descending sort puts `'Yes'` rows first. Then, the second sort criteria orders rows within the groups by descending `id`.

Note that, as commented by [ChrisG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11699746/chrisg), if `'Yes'` and `'No'` are the only possible values, this can be simplified as:

```
order by item_featured desc, id desc
```

This works because, string-wise, `'Yes'` is greater than `'No'`.

Comment: definitely the correct answer, if item_featured just allow YES/NO you could also go by `item_featured DESC, id DESC`

Comment: @ChrisG: indeed, that's even simpler. I updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: two ways, same result; personally i prefer your way (means if i have this case, i make it like that)

Comment: However, a small doubt, is the simplified one reliable? I mean the 1st one is based purely on condition and data whereas 2nd one on string length of Yes/No.

Comment: @RedStarEntertainment: the simplified option is just fine, as long as you only have "Yes" or "No" values. It *might* even perform marginally better.